# App Crash Immediately after initiating Quickblox video call from web to iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox, videocall

I have try to video call using QuickBlox from web page to iOS app but when I am call from web immediately iOS app crash with as below log.

```
[3553:77957] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10e546c78'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c7127e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff513fbb20 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c91fd4 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c75c4c ___forwarding___ + 1436
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c77f78 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   libswiftFoundation.dylib            0x000000010f8849f5 $sSD10FoundationE26_forceBridgeFromObjectiveC_6resultySo12NSDictionaryC_SDyxq_GSgztFZ + 709
    6   libswiftFoundation.dylib            0x000000010f8789e3 $sSD10FoundationE36_unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveCySDyxq_GSo12NSDictionaryCSgFZ + 67
    7   ProjectDemo                         0x000000010d71912a $s15ProjectDemo6HomeVCC20didReceiveNewSession_8userInfoySo12QBRTCSessionC_SDyS2SGSgtFTo + 138
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c7820c __invoking___ + 140
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c753af -[NSInvocation invoke] + 319
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23c75684 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 68
    11  Quickblox                           0x000000010e4cb67e qb_jid + 89448
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010fb97dd4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010fb98d48 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010fba6de6 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1500
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bd4049 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bceca9 __CFRunLoopRun + 2329
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23bce066 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff384c0bb0 GSEventRunModal + 65
    19  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48092d4d UIApplicationMain + 1621
    20  ProjectDemo                         0x000000010d75a98b main + 75
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff5227ec25 start + 1
    22  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
2020-09-01 09:56:40:474 ProjectDemo[3553:1260b] SEND: <a xmlns="urn:xmpp:sm:3" h="2"/>
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: The issue is `-[__NSCFConstantString count]: unrecognized selector` we dont have enough information to find the cause of the issue, you need to investigate where that is called and why it is calling a wrong selector

Comment: Hi there, please read this before posting future questions on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the issue is related to outdated Javascript SDK.

Per our check, your Javascript SDK version is 2.8.1. Please update SDK to the latest version 2.12.9: https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-javascript-sdk

Also, make sure that you are using the latest iOS SDK version 2.17.4: https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk